# WPF: How to set the data template trigger for content control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to create a user control that contains one combo box and a content control. The choice made in the combo box should determine the data template the content control would use. I've read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543515/wpf-reapply-datatemplateselector-when-a-certain-value-changes) which pretty much demonstrates what I am trying to achieve.

The combo box is filled with the `enum ModelType` values, which can be `Person` or `Company`. If the user chooses `Person`, the content control should use the `personTemplate` data template; and `companyTemplate` for `Company`.

I got stuck with the XAML code for the content control. Here is what I have created but I can't make it work:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  ...
  <DataTemplate x:Key="personTemplate" ...>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="companyTemplate" ...>
  ...
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<ContentControl x:Name="Account">
  <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AccountType}" Value="Person">
        <!-- I doubt the Value property is set correctly. -->
        <!-- It should be a value of an enum ModelType -->
          <Setter 
              TargetName="Account" 
              Property="ContentTemplate" 
              Value="{StaticResource personTemplate}" />
          <!-- The setter is unaware of the target name, i.e. content control -->
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AccountType}" Value="Company">
          <Setter 
              TargetName="Account" 
              Property="ContentTemplate" 
              Value="{StaticResource companyTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>                    
</ContentControl>
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Little sidenote: The template has to be a DataTemplate not a ControlTemplate

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I actually got it to work. :)

Here's what the XAML is supposed to look like:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
  <ContentControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AccountType}" Value="Person">
          <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource personTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AccountType}" Value="Company">
          <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource companyTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

The values of the enum also work well.

Comment: Do you have a tip jar somewhere?  How can I send you a beer?

Comment: be sure not to put a default value as  <ContentControl ContentTemplate="..defaultTemplate.." ... - triggers won't work. You can set default value in a setter: <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="..defaultTemplate.."