# In the ListBoxItem template, how do I change the visual state of the item based upon IsSelected?

Tags: wpf, listbox

I'm wanting to increase the size of a selected item in a ListBox and show extra controls.  I'm not sure how the ListBoxItem template knows whether the item is selected or not.  In the past I would wrap all of my items in radio buttons but it is very clunky and didn't utilize the ListBox selection at all. I would really like to have a better way.  Ideally, I would like the change to be in a visual state so I can animate the transition.

Thanks.

Comment: See this SO question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771362/wpf-how-to-set-the-data-template-trigger-for-content-control, what you want to do is trigger on the `IsSelected` property.

Comment: @CodingGorilla, not really what I want. Looking for a way of animating a transition when an item is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListBoxItem already defines the visual states `Selected` and `Unselected`. See [ListBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242%28v=vs.100%29) for how the ControlTemplate in ListBoxItem's default style handles these states.

Comment: I'm not sure how any of this information helps me. Could you give me some code?  How is the visual state of the `ItemTemplate` changed based upon with the `ListBoxItem`'s `IsSelected` value. I guess I'm confused.

Comment: Visual state changes are performed by the ListBoxItem. You don't have to change state in your code. Simply declare your own `<VisualState x:Name="Selected">` and `<VisualState x:Name="Unselected">` in the ControlTemplate our your ListBoxItem Style and animate whatever you like. Take the ListBoxItem's default style as an example of how to declare VisualStates.