# ContentControl is failing to bind to DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm unable to bind the `<ContentControl Content={Binding Type}/>` to the local resources `<DataTemplate>` when binding my custom property on my POCO class called `Type` (I'm hoping it's not down to the bad choice of naming).

**ReportItemModel**

```
public class ReportItemModel
{
        public ReportItemModel(string name, ReportItemType itemType, Type type)
        {
            Name = name;
            ItemType = itemType;
            Type = type;
        }

        public string Name { get; }
        public ReportItemType ItemType  { get; }
        public Type Type { get; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Type}"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">

      <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type moduleTypes:ReportModule}">
                   <Label>Test</Label>
             </DataTemplate>
      </ContentControl.Resources>

</ContentControl>
```

The `Type` property is (as you've probably guessed) a `System.Type` and the output within my WPF application is always the output of `ToString()` which I'm guessing is down to a failed match of my `<DataTemplate>`. If I change the `ContentControl` to `Content={Binding}` and set the `<DataTemplate>` to accept the data type of the POCO class `ReportItemModel` it works as intended. The only difference I can see is that `ReportItemModel` has been instantiated where as the `Type` property has not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was down to the XAML `DataType="{x:Type moduleTypes:ReportModule}"` calling behind the scenes `GetType()` on a `System.Type` which would always return a [`System.RuntimeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as the object was never instantiated and always (at that point) a `System.Type` (a *"Brain Fart"* moment to say the least). I was able to get around the issue by using a `ValueConverter` on the binding `<ContentControl Content={Binding Type}` and returning the `BaseClass` name as a `string`. Using the `BaseClass` name, It was easy enough to use a couple of`DataTriggers` which changed the `ContentTemplate` value to one of my matched custom `DataTemplate`'s using a similar method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771362/wpf-how-to-set-the-data-template-trigger-for-content-control).